# Flutter Firebase A value of type 'List<Future<CustomClass>>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List< CustomClass >?'

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

I am having an issue with my FutureBuilder in flutter. It's supposed to map the custom class 'GeoPost' to a 'List' from a firebase query but somewhere in my code it is not reading the Geopost list as a non Future

here is the code where the error occurs:

```
FutureBuilder(
            future: postsRef.get().then((doc) {
              geoPosts = doc.docs.map((doc) async => await GeoPost.fromDoc(doc)).toList();
            }),
            builder: (context, snapshot) { }
```

custom class and functions:

```
    class GeoPost {
      final String caption;
      final String postId;
      final String authorId;
      final int likesCount;
      final int commentCount;
      final Position position;
      final Timestamp timeStamp;
      final String? imageUrl;
      final Userdata authordata;
    
      GeoPost(this.caption, this.postId, this.authorId, this.likesCount, this.commentCount, this.position, this.timeStamp, this.imageUrl, this.authordata);
    
      static Future<GeoPost> fromDoc(DocumentSnapshot doc) async {
        return GeoPost.fromDocument(doc, await getPostUserDataFromFirestore(doc['userId']));
    
      }
    
      factory GeoPost.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc, Userdata author) {
        return GeoPost(
            doc['caption'],
            doc['postId'],
            doc['userId'],
            doc['likeCount'] ?? 0,
            doc['commentCount'] ?? 0,
            doc['position'],
            doc['timeStamp'],
            doc['imageUrl'],
            author
        );
      }

Future<void> getPostUserDataFromFirestore (String did) async {
    return Userdata.fromDoc(await usersRef.doc(uid).get());
  }
    }
```

error:

```
Error: A value of type 'List<Future<GeoPost>>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<GeoPost>?'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You need to wait for all the Futures in the `List<Future<GeoPost>` (which converts them into a `List<GeoPost>`) before assiging them to a variable of type `List<GeoPost>`.

  *Update your `FutureBuilder` code to this:*

  ```dart
  FutureBuilder<List<GeoPost>>(
    future: () async { 
      var doc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collectionPath').get();
      var data = doc.docs.map((doc) async => await GeoPost.fromDoc(doc)).toList();
      geoPosts = await Future.wait(data);
      return geoPosts;
    }(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) { }
  ```
- Also, you need to change the return type of the `getPostUserDataFromFirestore` method from `Future<void>` to `Future<Userdata>`. `void` is used when there is no value returned.

  Update the `getPostUserDataFromFirestore` method to this:

  ```dart
  Future<Userdata> getPostUserDataFromFirestore (String did) async {
    return Userdata.fromDoc(await usersRef.doc(uid).get());
  }
  ```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working now I'm just receiving this error: "The argument type 'Future<List<GeoPost>?> Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<Object?>?'."

Comment: Don't forget to add the two brackets i.e "()" at the end of the future function.
The brackets return the result instead of passing the function.

Comment: I put the function outside the widget tree and now it seems to be working fine now but that's good to know. thanks so much